# How to change an exception event back to an instance event using Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have created a recurring event "Weekly Thursday Meetings", with recurrence [RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TH] starting date April 08, 2021. By accident/mistake some exceptions have been added to the recurring event, for example for date April 29, 2021 and June 03, 2021. When a new attendee is added to the recurring event, invite notifications are sent out for the master event as well as for April 29 and June 03. Actually we have hundreds of exceptions created so when a new attendee is added to the guest list, the new attendee receives hundreds of invites one for each exception.

Now I need to clean up the recurring event so that when a new attendee is added to the recurring event, only one invite notification is sent, not hundreds of notifications, while the calendar still keeps the events for all the days, including April 29 2021 and June 03 2021.

This is what I tried:

1. I tried to cancel all the exceptions, but that triggered sending a cancelation notification for every exception (hundreds).
2. I also tried to delete all the exceptions.

- delete all the exceptions. All the exceptions were gone and there was no notification sent to the new attendee.
- I updated the recurring event to have only two instances with the recurrence to [RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;**COUNT=2**;BYDAY=TH] before April 29, 2021.
- updated the recurring event again with no expiring date [RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TH] hoping to bring back the events for April 29, 2021 and June 03, 2021 as instance.
- but the events for April 29, 2021 and June 03, 2021 still appear as exceptions.

Is there any way to convert an exception back to a normal instance?

Comment: hi, not sure, perhaps it might be necessary to create a new event

Comment: Thank you @IronMan. We try not to create a new event because many attendees already responded. With a new event, the attendees will receive new invites and respond again. Forgot to mention, this is for Google Calendar.

Comment: If delete the event, the attendees receive canceled event notifications each for one  exception.

Comment: This doesnt seam programming related to me may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/?  If im wrong please include your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change an event through the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar) you can [`patch`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) or [`delete`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete) it without sending notifications you can set the parameter `sendUpdates` to `none` (in both cases).

The description of the `sendUpdates` parameter is as follows:

> Guests who should receive notifications about the deletion of the event.
>
> Acceptable values are:
>
> - "all": Notifications are sent to all guests.
> - "externalOnly": Notifications are sent to non-Google Calendar guests only.
> - "none": No notifications are sent. This value should only be used for migration use cases (note that in most migration cases the import method should be used).

You could easy delete all the exceptions you don't care anymore or patch the one that you need to modify without sending a modification to every single person per exception.

#### Reference

- Try to read the [official documentation on recurring events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents)

Comment: Thank you @Raserhin for your reply. The problem is I care for all the events. I don't want to delete any of them. So for those exceptions, I need them to be back as instances. I was able to delete the exceptions without notification being sent `service.events() .delete(calendarId, event.getId()).execute();`, but I don't want the events for those exception dates to be gone, I want them still be in the calendar as normal instance. But when the events re-appear (by changing the recurrence rule), the events for April 29, 2021 and June 03, 2021 still appear as exceptions.

Comment: It seems once an instance becomes an exception, it cannot be changed back to instance?

Comment: I think that indeed is not possible. Maybe you could try to request that kind of  [Missing Features](https://developers.google.com/calendar/support#missing_features).